# How to implement jquery script in selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, selenium

I've created a script as the I want to use in another Selenium `WebDriver` script:

```
$function() {
    $("pane1").hide(300);
});
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to call this script in my Selenium java code.

Comment: Please specify more detail? What you want to call? and for what?

Comment: I want to call the jquery as seen above in a webdriver script I have created. I want the script to be called and hide the element pane1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling jQuery functions from Selenium is done exactly the same way as calling any other. However, there are two issues with your code:

1. You have `$function`, where you probably mean `$(function`. If you tried to execute the code in your question as-is you certainly got an error because of this.
2. Ok, let's say you fix that problem. Now you have a `$(function () {...})` call. This is not harmful but it is pointless as you are essentially saying "execute this function when the page has finished its initial load". If you use Selenium the way it is usually used, it won't return control to you until the page has finished its initial load, so there is no reason to wait for the page load.

So:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("$('pane1').hide(300);");
```

Comment: What would I do if it is a very large script with many functions I wish to call?

Comment: Pass the large script to `executeScript`. I've passed fairly large scripts to it. I don't know of any hard limit to the script size. However, I'm pretty sure it was not design to execute super large code bases so I would not be surprised if beyond a certain size Selenium would choke, even if there is no hardcoded limit.

Comment: An example of passing the large script would be greatly appreciated if you could give one?thanks